# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: server, apache2, localhost, virtualhost, hosts

This is how my virtual hosts `the-square.local.conf` looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t>
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin admin@the_square.com
ServerAlias the-square.local
ServerName the-square.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/the_square/public

<Directory /var/www/html/the_square/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
</Directory>
# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/the-square.local-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/the-square.local-access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I already have enabled the site `sudo a2ensite the-square.local`

And I also added on `/etc/hosts` under the `127.0.0.6    the_square.local`.

I already restarted apache 2 `systemctl reload apache2`.

Also I did `sudo chmod -R 755` and `777` also to the project.

I have other virtual hosts working without problems but I can't find the problem this time.

Thank you!

- Edit: I changed the project name to `thesquare` and also did in all configurations this change but still the same error...

Comment: Hi, change the relevant line to `127.0.0.1  localhost  the_square.local`. Your entry contains `.conf` that is wrong. Also you do not need the ServerAlias directive, because the ServerName is exactly the same.

Comment: in reality does not contain `.conf` I made a mistake writing it on question because I was hurrying

Comment: it is `127.0.0.6 the_square.local` already and shows that error

Comment: Change the underscore `_` to a dash `-` … underscores are not allowed in domain names.

Comment: let me give a try

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Try to use an incognito window it cold e a cache issue.

Comment: I died cleared the cache and also tried to open on incogito but again without success

Comment: @MarinarioAgalliu I posted an answer with more information on these three rather ambiguous issues... I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on the possibility of using an underscore `_` in a domain name are a bit ambiguous from a theory standpoint. But it is for sure not encouraged in modern practices. A domain name with an underscore in it will most likely be both not resolve and not allowed by modern systems. The same goes for host-names as well and even Apache's `DocumentRoot` in some cases.

Please see this post for example:

[Can (domain name) subdomains have an underscore “_” in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180465/can-domain-name-subdomains-have-an-underscore-in-it)

And this post related to Apache's `DocumentRoot`:

[Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925672/bad-request-your-browser-sent-a-request-that-this-server-could-not-understand)

It is worth noting as well that the TLD [`.local`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) might not be fully supported on all DNS revolvers and in this case the TLD `.localdomain` might be used instead.

Comment: The fact is that the virtual host is redirecting me to the initial login page as the project setup but still says not found

Comment: so it is redirecting since the first time to `the-square.local/login` as it should but it says Not Found

Comment: @MarinarioAgalliu Please read the second linked post about Apache's `DocumentRoot` and remove the underscore from that as well... there are three issues I mentioned in the answer... Please go over all the three and change accordingly... As I said it is a bit ambiguous and information on the internet are a bit outdated regarding these three issues.

Comment: I changed the name of the project to the-square and changed from `_` to `-` but still not working. I did restarted apache again.

Comment: If I add `phpinfo();` and right after `die();` to the starting file of the project (`index.php` since is Laravel project)  it will show me php info page without problems. Strange...

Comment: @MarinarioAgalliu in this case I would check the PHP code for any redirects or references to the old URL or document root directory and change them to the new ones accordingly.

Comment: I will check up and if I find the issue I will post the answer here.